# Proving 2 lines orthogonal in a regular tetrahedron

Tags: geometry

If $ABCD$ is a regular tetrahedron where $AB=b$.

[image: image of regular tetrahedron]

$I,J,K,$ and $L$ are the midpoints of $[AB],[BC],[CD],$ and $[AD]$ respectively. I proved $(AB)$ orthogonal to $(CD)$.
What would be the nature of $IJKL$?

I proved it to be a rhombus where I applied midpoint theorem to triangles $ABC, ADB, BCD,$ and $ACD$ to show that $IJ=JK=KL=IL=\frac {AC} 2=\frac {BD}2=\frac b 2 $

Could it possibly be a square? How ?

Comment: The Midpoint theorem doesn't just imply that the midsegment is half as long as a side of a triangle; it also implies that the midsegment is *parallel* to that side of the triangle. Thus, two sides of $\square IJKL$ are parallel to $\overline{AC}$, and two are parallel to $\overline{BD}$. By your previous work, you know that $\overline{AC}\perp \overline{BD}$. Consequently, the rhombus is indeed a square.

Comment: how is AC perpendicular to BD?@Blue

Comment: You proved $\overline{AB}$ orthogonal to $\overline{CD}$. It's the same thing: any pair of opposite edges of a regular tetrahedron are orthogonal.

Comment: how could I write it in detail to prove it @Blue

Comment: Didn't you write that you'd already proven it? ... hmmm ... Well, one of my favorite facts about regular tetrahedra is that they share vertices with a cube. Opposite edges of the tetrahedron correspond to diagonals of opposite faces of that cube that are "obviously" orthogonal. You can prove this formally by using convenient coordinates for the vertices of the cube, say $(\pm 1, \pm 1, \pm 1)$. (The tetrahedron's vertices will be the ones with an odd number of "$+1$"s, or an odd number of "$-1$"s, if you prefer.)

Comment: I proved that AB is orthogonal to CD by proving AB is orthogonal to plane ICD and thus orthogonal to CD Can I prove it (BD) orthogonal to (AC) in a such a way @Blue

Comment: That works, too. :)  Anyway ... If you've proved it once, then you don't have to prove it again. Every pair of opposite edges of a regular tetrahedron are alike due to symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
If you take the midpoints of all the six edges, you will obtain the vertices of a smaller regular octahedron. $I$, $J$, $K$, $L$ are four of the vertices.
You may draw the octahedron to visualize the $4$ vertices.